# Program crashes when blitting pictures in a list

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to blit multiple pictures to the screen using a list and appending the coordinates into separate lists.

In a list, with the name of the pictures, I want it to output and when a bullet collides with the image I remove it from the list so it gets removed from the screen. But I haven't made the collision detection yet.

Also, when I run it using these functions the program just crashes it doesn't have any errors or anything.

```
#create enemies
lvl1 = [[alien2],[alien2],[alien1]]

def create_alien_list(level_list):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    i = 0
    alien_w = 0
    alien_h = 0
    for row in level_list:
        x = 10
        for col in row:
            if col: level_list[i].append([x,y])
            x += alien_w + 10
        i+=1
        b_y += alien_h + 5

def draw_aliens():
    i = 0
    for each in alien_list:
        screen.blit(level_list[i],(level_list[i][1],level_list[i][2]))
        i+=1
```

Comment: If there truly is no error, then it probably hasn't crashed. If you are running this in Windows, you should run it from the command line so that you can see any error traceback. It's quite possible that it did crash but you're just not seeing the error.

As it stands, it's hard to debug your code because it's clear that much of the important code has been left out, as nothing at all useful would happen with just the above code. What calls create_alien_list and draw_aliens? What variable is level_list? How are you sure the error is in this particular code?

Comment: Are you sure create_alien_list and draw_aliens are operating on the same list?  You don't pass the list as an argument to draw_aliens.

Comment: You may want to make each alien a [sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and create a display [group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) instead. That way you can easily implement the [pygame sprite collision](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) and also use the [`sprite.kill()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#Sprite.kill) sequence to help remove the character on death.

Comment: Yes i am sure that it is this code because when i run the program with the functions it doesn't work and no errors come up in python shell then when i don't use the functions it runs fine.

Comment: and i'm using the lvl1 list in the function and i just relized i don't use the same list in both functions. the for in alien_list:

Comment: should be level_list. sorry for all the comments i keep accidentaly pressing the enter key

Comment: and if you need the rest of the code i can post it

Comment: Well if you still have the issue after you fixed the code, then I'd check out what other code might be causing the issue and posting that too.

Answer (score 2):

Your "draw_aliens" function is not passing an image as first argument to the `blit` method, as it should be.  Looking at the code attached here, one can see that `level_list[i]  is a list - ot an image. So, if this is not a trancribing error, just vhange your blitting line to:

`screen.blit(level_list[i][0],(level_list[i][1],level_list[i][2]))` instead. If you indeed is getting no error messages, it may be due to a faulty parameter verification in Pygame's blit code which is segfaulting your program.

Comment: It still didn't work it opens up the window then the windows popup pops up saying the program has stopped working and all that crap. and i'm pretty sure the error is only in the create_alien_list() because when i only use that it doesn't work. I have no clue what the problem is and i sent it to two of my uncles and one of them is really busy and the other looked at it and can't figure out what the problem is either.